# Navigation overriding other divs

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a top menu in my wordpress blog that includes 3 divs: one div for navigation, one for social icons and one for the search bar.

The navigation div is overriding the others, so they lost completely its funcionalities.

If I set a lower value for the width, it changes the whole appearance of the menu. And it also has its mobile version, so I need it to be 100%.

Any suggestions?

Here's the link: http://ahseamodapega.provisorio.ws/

Comment: Please post your code!

Comment: I use firebug to see the code.. it's impossible to post it here because there's a lot of classes involved....  the code is huge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding z-index property, see below css code:

```
#MenuFixoTop {
    position: relative;
    width: 100% !important;
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 0;
}

.nav-search {
    padding: 18px 0;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -293px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .nav-search {
        padding: 18px 0;
        float: right;
         margin-right: 0;
        right: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I set the width to 70%, the div goes to the center..... instead of being aligned to the left.....

Comment: there's also a javascript that animates it when the page is scrolled.. the script sets the menuright margin to 0 and to 40px automatically....

Comment: See my updated code, If this helps.

Comment: z-index: 0; on #MenuFixoTop  solved for the social icons div! Now they are clickable again....

but the search bar is still useless...

Comment: I have given you code for search bar

Comment: I used it... but nothing happened!

Comment: Have you added it on website? I can not see the media query code

Comment: Sorry, it was missing the "@media (min-width: 768px) {..." part

Comment: Now my search bar is almost out of the screen....

Comment: You need to get rid of margin-right. make it 0.

Comment: Now it works perfectly on the desktop site... but it's all messed up in the mobile ;(

Comment: My mistake, it was missing a closing "}"... 

But now, how can I remove these paddings from the collapsing mobile menu?

Comment: It should not affect mobile because we have written media query to target desktop

Comment: So there might be something else wrong.... I can find it.... but the collapse menu is not 100% of the screen as it used to be!

Comment: Solved... in fact it wasn't this....!

Thanks for the support! :))))) And sorry to botter you with all these questions!!

Comment: Welcome. No problem :)